# Wristwatches in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

So there's references in many of the Star Wars novels to "chronometers" "chronos" and other wristwatches but we never see anything besides wrist comlinks for obvious reasons (not important to the plot). What does a wristwatch in Star Wars look like and are there any descriptions or pictures in any of the EU material?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chronometer

Answer (score 4):

We see at least one good example of a [Wrist Chrono](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chronometer) in the Star Wars: The Clone Wars episode *[Weapons Factory](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Weapons_Factory)*. It is, as you would imagine, a glowing dial with numbers on it, in this case being used as a stopwatch (and manually reset to 00:00:00), but normally described as showing a twelve-hour digital clock.

> **Luminara:** *We'll monitor your progress on these chronometers.*
>
> [image]